# Copy data from one list to another in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to loop from one list to another.

```csharp
var monthlySchedule = db.StudioSchedules.ToList();

List<CalenderColumns> ObjCal = new List<CalenderColumns>();

foreach (var item in monthlySchedule)
{
    ObjCal = new List<CalenderColumns>()
    {                    
        new CalenderColumns 
        {
            id = item.ID, name = item.Description,
            startdate = item.Date.ToString(), enddate=item.Date.ToString(),
            starttime =item.StartTime, endtime=item.EndTime,
            color ="#99CCCC", url="" 
        }
    };
}

Console.WriteLine(ObjCal);
```

First I tell the program to put `monthlySchedule` into a list. Which contains 4 rows of data

[image]

Then I make a new list called ObjCal from a public class

```
public class CalenderColumns
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string startdate { get; set; }
    public string enddate { get; set; }
    public string starttime { get; set; }
    public string endtime { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

Next, I write a `foreach` loop of `monthlySchedule` which contains the 4 rows to add it to `ObjCal`

**The issue is** the foreach loop is only getting the last row but I'm trying to get all 4 rows. Shown below
[image]

**Goal:** To have all 4 rows of data in ObjCal

Comment: SO does not have a duplicate target for "how to add item to an existing list"... That's unfortunate. We'll have plenty answers here then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why your current solution isn't working:

Instead of adding the items to your `ObjCal` list you are currently creating a new list for each item (you are calling `new List<CalenderColumns>()` *inside* the loop). This newly created list (which contains only one item as specified in the object initializer) is then stored in the `ObjCal` variable. This is repeated for as many times as you have elements in `monthlySchedule` leaving you finally with a list which only contains the *last* element of `monthlySchedule` (resulting from the last iteration of the `foreach` loop).

#### How you can fix it:

What you want to do is to add each item to the *existing* list (which you rightfully created *before* the `foreach` loop). Items can be added to a list by calling the `Add()` method and passing the item you want to add to it. As you want to add all elements to the `ObjCal` the call to `Add()` should be placed *inside* of the `foreach` loop (so that it's repeated for all elements). One possible solution may therefore look like this:

```csharp
foreach (var item in monthlySchedule)
{
    CalenderColumns columns = new CalenderColumns 
    {
        id = item.ID, name = item.Description,
        startdate = item.Date.ToString(), enddate=item.Date.ToString(),
        starttime =item.StartTime, endtime=item.EndTime,
        color ="#99CCCC", url="" }
    };  
    // don't create a new list but add the new entry to the existing 
    // list we created before entrering the loop                
    ObjCal.Add(columns);
}
```

or if you prefer LINQ:

```csharp
var monthlySchedule = db.StudioSchedules.ToList();

List<CalenderColumns> ObjCal = monthlySchedule
    .Select(item => new CalenderColumns 
    {
        id = item.ID, name = item.Description,
        startdate = item.Date.ToString(), enddate=item.Date.ToString(),
        starttime =item.StartTime, endtime=item.EndTime,
        color ="#99CCCC", url="" 
    })
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(ObjCal);
```

note that you have to add `using System.Linq` if you go for the second solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing your List in every interaction of your loop.

You just need to move the initialization of your List outside the loop and add the method `.Add();` inside your loop.

Like below:

```
  var monthlySchedule = db.StudioSchedules.ToList();

    List<CalenderColumns> ObjCal = new List<CalenderColumns>();

    ObjCal = new List<CalenderColumns>();
    foreach (var item in monthlySchedule)
    {
        ObjCal.Add(                    
        new CalenderColumns {
            id = item.ID, name = item.Description,
            startdate = item.Date.ToString(), enddate=item.Date.ToString(),
            starttime =item.StartTime, endtime=item.EndTime,
            color ="#99CCCC", url="" }
        });
    }

    Console.WriteLine(ObjCal);
```